# Using detectron2 to train Mask RCNN custom instance segmentation to find confusion matrix, f1 score, IOU

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, evaluation, detectron

I am using detectron2 and pytorch for doing a custom object detection (Mask RCNN).
[Evaluation result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmQgx.png)
So, above image is the evaluation result for my training. How to code for the accuracy, precision, F1 score and confusion matrix?
The training code I take from
https://github.com/ahmad12hamdan99/Rovers_vs_Cars/blob/main/detectron2.ipynb

Below I show example code of training, also get from above link

```
trainer = DefaultTrainer(cfg) 
trainer.resume_or_load(resume=False)
trainer.train()

# Look at training curves in tensorboard:
%reload_ext tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir $OUTPUT_DIR_PATH

cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = os.path.join(cfg.OUTPUT_DIR, 
"model_final.pth")
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.SCORE_THRESH_TEST = 0.7
predictor = DefaultPredictor(cfg)

dataset_valid = DatasetCatalog.get(VALID_DATA_SET_NAME)

for d in dataset_valid: 
    img = cv2.imread(d["file_name"])
    outputs = predictor(img)
    
    visualizer = Visualizer(
        img[:, :, ::-1],
        metadata=metadata, 
        scale=0.8, 
        instance_mode=ColorMode.IMAGE_BW
    )
    out = 





  visualizer.draw_instance_predictions(outputs["instances"].
       to("cpu"))cv2_imshow(out.get_image()[:, :, ::-1])

from detectron2.evaluation import COCOEvaluator, 
 inference_on_dataset
from detectron2.data import build_detection_test_loader
evaluator = COCOEvaluator("Segmentation-test", 
output_dir=cfg.OUTPUT_DIR)
val_loader = build_detection_test_loader(cfg, "Segmentation-test")
print(inference_on_dataset(predictor.model, val_loader, evaluator))
```